# enable or disable checkbox from javascript not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<legend>Information</legend>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
       <label><strong>{{$val}}</strong></label>
    </div>
    <script>
        var str = "Hello world!";
        var res = str.substring(0, 2);
        if (res == ee) {
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
        } else if (res == he) {
            document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
        }
    </script>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="operator" id="checkbox" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="operator" id="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="operator" id="checkbox">
    </div>
</div>
          
<br/>
```

i have included my html piece of code above. i don't know why check box is not responding for this piece of JavaScript.
note: i should use  JavaScript in the position between div's

Comment: Please use class for this! Use unique id's! Never use same id's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

value `ee` and `he` should be wrapped in quotes. also note that IDs should be unique, you can rather use common class and use `getElementsByClassName` to target all of them using class :

```
var res = str.substring(0, 2);
if(res=='ee'){
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
else if(res=='he'){
  document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox").checked = true;
}
```

Comment: see this js fiddle jsfiddle.net/vcbwrg0L/1 still its not working

Comment: @VijayKumar: `H` should be capital in he or convert substring to lowercase and then compare. http://jsfiddle.net/peokog8m/

Comment: @VijayKumar: check the fiddle which i shared. script should be there after dom element.

Comment: can i concatenate two strings for id of input fields like <input type="checkbox" name="operator" id="'11' + '00'" >

Answer (score 0):

Condition is wrong. If you want check the string element you have to use `""` or `''`. Otherwise it will treat as a variable.

```
  if(res=="ee"){
     alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
   }
   else if(res=="he"){
     document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
   }
```